# Python script to forward all traffic on a specific port to a remote proxy

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, portforwarding

Id like to route all traffic on port (80) to a remote server xx.xx.xxx.xx/xxxx using python on a windows platform.

I am not sure how to do this with python since Ive been using cmd to make this happen in the past.

Comment: Stack Overflow works best when you post examples of your code, state what you have tried and what works and does not work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: I have no idea where to start with this. I know how to do it with a batch file but not with a python file.

Comment: @sunbird you should use something other than python like SSH tunneling or l2tp (but I don't know how, just giving you an idea).